# Make cordova.exec synchronous

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In android using phonegap i.e cordova2.9, I am searching for a way to make this call synchronous :

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
cordova.exec(onSuccess, fail, "PluginName", "echo",["arg1","arg2"]); 
}
```

I have noticed that the function onSuccess gets triggered at the very end of the loop i.e after i becomes equal to 5

Answer (score 1):

Cordova is asynchronous.

If it was using synchronous calls, the UI would be stuck during the execution of the loop.

To achieve what you're trying to do, you should increment and test the value of i inside of the onSuccess and fail callbacks.

Maybe something like this would work (no much time to test it/really think about it) :

```
var execute=function(val,max){
    if(val<max){
        cordova.exec(function(){
            onSuccess();
            execute(val+1,max);
        }, function(){
            fail();
            execute(val+1,max);
        },
        "PluginName", "echo",["arg1","arg2"]); 
    }
}
execute(0,5);
```